# Filter values as per std deviation for individual column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a requirement where I need to assign particular value to NaN based on the variable upper, which is my upper range of standard deviation
Here is a sample code-

```
    data = {'year': ['2014','2014','2015','2014','2015','2015','2015','2014','2015'], 
        'month':['Hyundai','Toyota','Hyundai','Toyota','Hyundai','Toyota','Hyundai','Toyota',"Toyota"],
        'make': [23,34,32,22,12,33,44,11,21]
       }
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
    df=pd.pivot_table(df,index='month',columns='year',values='make',aggfunc=np.sum)
    upper=df.mean() + 3*df.std()
```

This is just the sample data, the real data is huge, based on upper's value for every year, I need to filter the year column accordingly.

Sample I/P's:-

df-

[image]

upper std dev-

[image]

Desired O/P-

Based on the upper std deviation values in individual year, it should convert value as NaN if the value<upper.
Eg 2014 has upper=138, so only in 2014's column, if value<upper, convert it to NaN.
2014's upper value is only applicable in 2014 itself, and the same goes for 2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC use [`DataFrame.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html) for compare Dataframe by `Series` and then set `NaN`s if match by [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
print (df.lt(upper))
year     2014  2015
month              
Hyundai  True  True
Toyota   True  True
```

---

```
df = df.mask(df.lt(upper))
print (df)
year     2014  2015
month              
Hyundai   NaN   NaN
Toyota    NaN   NaN
```

Comment: How would I see what were the NaN value here before too. Its the same query as I posted in my previous post.